# Need to calculate the surface of an Object in C

Tags: c

Im writing a programm where i scan a number n, which is the amount of points this object has. (Twodimensional). Im supposed to calculate its surface.

This is my current code:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned int i,j,m,n;
        printf("Wieviele Eckpunkte hat ihre Form? \n n = ");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        printf("\n Ihre Form hat %u Eckpunkte \n",n);

        int x[n][2];

        for(i=0;i < n; i++) {
            for(j=0; j < 2; j++) {
                if(j == 0) {
                printf("Punkt%u X-Wert = ",i+1);
            }
                else if (j == 1) {
                   printf("Punkt%u Y-Wert = ",i+1);
                }
                scanf("%u",&(x[i][j]));
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                printf("%u\t", x[i][j]);
        }
                printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0;i < n; i++) {
        //Calculation of the surface
        printf("%u",a);
    }
        return 0;

}
```

The calculation is supposed to work by taking 2 points, making a triangle out of those to points and the point 0/0 which lies in the middle of the object, and calculate all those trangles together. How do i do that last part?

Comment: You question isn't clear. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65273547/edit) to make it more clear.

Comment: Explain the Calculation part in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a triangle given three coordinates is

```
(x1(y2 - y3) + x2(y3 - y1) + x3(y1 - y2)) / 2
```

Since x1 is (0,0), this reduces to

```
(x2*y3 - x3*y2) / 2.
```

Walk around the perimeter, point-by-point, adding all the areas, then add the area of the 'last' triangle, pN-to-p0.

Pay attention to whether the outer edge of a given triangle goes clockwise or counter-clockwise, you'll add the areas of one and subtract the areas of the other. In the end, take the absolute value of the result.